# Do scientific calculators (non-graphing calculators) have a free running clock?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, sleep, calculator, iot

I am taking a course on IoT devices and I was wondering how generic calculators achieve long battery life given they operate with no more than a couple of coin cells at best. In case they have a free running clock, what order of current does the clock generator/oscillator consume? In case they don't have a free running clock, how do they wake up from low power/sleep state? I am strictly asking about non graphing calculators like [this one](https://www.casio.com/intl/scientific-calculators/product.FX-991ESPLUS/) from Casio

Comment: Unless there is an actual real time clock (telling you time of day), most battery powered devices are going to turn off their oscillators when powered down in order to save battery life.  When you push a power button the oscillator will be restarted.

Comment: Hardware interrupt on wake functionality on the controller.

Comment: LCD displays are dynamic and require flipping at a slow rate. So a clock is likely required for that, although it need not be fast - the actual LCD display is very very low-power (any backlight is not low-power in comparison). But during display, the calculating engine can be asleep until a button is pressed.

Comment: @user1850479 Note that my graphics calculator (fx 9750GII) had a real-time clock in hardware, which was not accessible from the operating system.

Comment: I can't speak definitively for calculators but a technique is to run the display driver and a key detector that can awaken the CPU. Then the CPU awakes on a keypress, processes in response, updates the display then goes to sleep. Sleep stops the CPU clock and all peripherals except display and key detect.

Comment: A casio wristwatch will run 5-7 years on a lithium battery, while leaving it's LCD and RTC active the whole time.   So for sure, these functions do not consume much energy at all.   Lot's of TI and Casio calculators work with just office light hitting a meager little solar panel, that's not a high-energy source for sure!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculators use something like a mask-programmed 4-bit MCU, though more modern ones are not characterized as MCUs.

A typical fairly capable one from some years ago is the [MSM5055](https://usermanual.wiki/m/5f5f9c8bc97ee1d96c85cc855e9919f02611aaaf8c73cae9de27d50a55b1cf44.pdf). Note that this kind of part is mask-programmed so the program had to be developed using a very expensive emulator system, then sent off to the semiconductor manufacturer and you'd get the chips back in a couple months. Large minimum order and substantial mask charges applied. If there was a problem in the program, well you could throw the chips away and order more. But very nice performance for this kind of application.

This one operates from a 32.768kHz watch crystal so it can keep time, and the instruction time is 122.1us (~8kHz). Operating current is typical 3uA so it won't add much to self-discharge of a battery. The LCD display will draw a bit more current, somewhat dependent on the area of the segments that are on.

Calculators can be made with modern 8-bit, or even 32-bit MCUs but they tend to eat batteries more aggressively even when available sleep modes are properly employed. For example, the modernized HP15C limited edition calculator consumes batteries much faster than the original. Larger multiplexed alphanumeric displays such as that used on the HP48G also tend to require more current than segment static LCD displays.

---

Illustrating the business risks in mask-programmed calculator chips is [this](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.3023318?journalCode=pto) advertisement from 1976 which offered a (very slightly) buggy scientific calculator for a then-extremely low price due to 50,000 chips being produced with a small firmware issue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your example has an "on"-button, which will be used to trigger a startup of the processor including clocks.

All calculators I owned had that (aside from a cheap photocell-only powered one that simply didn't work without light), so I'd assume that's the standard way of dealing with this.

But: it's also worth noting that low-power clocked modes don't really need much current; IIRC, the MSP430 microcontrollers with FRAM, which are quite universal microcontrollers, not single-purpose pocket calculator ASICs, can maintain their real-time clock at less than 0.5 µA (but that really just means a 16 kHz crystal is oscillated, and literally a hand full of transistors on average are counting up). Together with self-discharge, that means a 200 mAh coin cell should still last 30 to 40 years. So, that would also be pretty viable, if there was any application for that in calculators – but there isn't.